# Elasticsearch scripted field with value from another document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, aws-elasticsearch

Imagine that I have two type of documents:

- Customers - contains information such as region, locale, etc)
- Purchases - contain details about individual purchases).

There is a parent/child relationship between customers/purchases.

I need to generate a report which would contain all purchases that match certain filter criteria, but each row should also contain some lookup data from the customer doc (ex: locale of customer). I know that one of the ways to do this is to flatten data and put these fields directly into purchases doc in the first place. I would like to know if there is a way ElasticSearch could populate these fields automatically for me (maybe some scripted field lookup magic?) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to access fields from `parent/child` using any kind of  script, because it's completely different document. It would be very expensive to access parent from within the context of the child and vice versa.

[Inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-inner-hits.html) will do what you need:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "Customer": {},
    "Purchase": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "Customer"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/Customer/1
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}

PUT test/Purchase/2?parent=1
{
  "price": 100
}

GET test/Purchase/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
          "range":{
            "price":{
              "gte":10
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "has_parent":{
            "type":"Customer",
            "inner_hits":{},
            "query":{
              "match_all":{}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```